# Src Canvas Flickering

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to figure out how to switch images on a canvas without a small time of blankness in between.

To make my point here is an extreme example of this.  In this program, when your spacebar is held down it redraws the image circle.png every milisecond.  Because this is so fast the image  dissappears.

I did try to preload my image but it didn't help.

Here is my full code:

```
// Access Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameBoard");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


// preload image
var circleReady = false;
var circleImage = new Image();
circleImage.onload = function () {
    circleReady = true;
};
circleImage.src = "images/Circle.png";



// Game objects
var circle = {
};

// circle location
circle.x = canvas.width / 2;
circle.y = canvas.height / 2;

// Keyboard events
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);



// Update Objects

var update = function () {
    if (32 in keysDown) { // Player space pressed
        circleImage.src = "images/Circle.png"; //re-draws image
    }
};

// Draws Everything
var render = function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,609);

    if (circleReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(circleImage, circle.x, circle.y);
    }
};

// The main loop
var main = function () {
    update();
    render();

};

// Starts Function
var then = Date.now();
setInterval(main, 1); // Execute as fast as possible
```

Comment: You can have two canvases, one for each image. When you want to switch. Remove or hide the one in the front, leaving (instantly) the one in the back.

Comment: What happens when I want to have an image for each letter?  26 canvases. It's a great idea but when I have multiple images I don't think its a good enough solution.

Comment: 26 canvases total. But you can keep around only 2 at a time. And you can have *a lot* of canvases, if they aren't too large.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do that please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reloading the image in the update function which is causing your delay:

```
circleImage.src = "images/Circle.png"; //re-draws image
```

All you have to do is drawImage without reloading the image:

```
ctx.drawImage(circleImage, circle.x, circle.y);
```

Here is an example of an image loader that loads all your images before execution begins:

```
    var imageURLs=[];  // put the paths to your images here
    var imagesOK=0;
    var imgs=[];
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house1.jpg");
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house2.jpg");
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house3.jpg");
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house4.jpg");
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house5.jpg");
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house6.jpg");
    loadAllImages(start);

    function loadAllImages(callback){
        for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            imgs.push(img);
            img.onload = function(){ 
                imagesOK++; 
                if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                    callback();
                }
            };
            img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
            img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
            img.src = imageURLs[i];
        }      
    }

    function start(){
        // all your images are fully loaded so begin your app
    }
```

Comment: This is just an example.  In a program I am switching between two different images when I click spacebar and it flickers in between the switch.

Comment: Understood, the answer is the same:  (1) preload all images into an image array: var imageArray=[] (2) drawImage( imageArray[desiredImageIndex], 0,0)

Answer (score 0):

You can have two canvases, one for each image. When you want to switch. Remove or hide the one in the front, leaving (instantly) the one in the back.

Per your comment, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fCAZh/) is an example of 26 letters of the alphabet. We only keep two canvases at a time. Each time the user clicks whe add a new only, and make the hidden one visible, with no delay.

```
function createCanvas(letter) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = letter;
    canvas.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(canvas);

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconicon/alpha-magnets/128/Letter-'+letter+'-icon.png';
    image.onload = function() {
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    };

    return canvas;
}

createCanvas('a').style.display = '';
createCanvas('b');
var prevCharCode = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
var charCode = 'b'.charCodeAt(0);

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById(String.fromCharCode(charCode)).style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('container').removeChild(
        document.getElementById(String.fromCharCode(prevCharCode))
    );
    prevCharCode = charCode;
    if(++charCode > 'z'.charCodeAt(0)) {
      charCode = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
    }
    createCanvas(String.fromCharCode(charCode));
});
```